# Database Normalization 1nf-3nf (Is this compliant?)

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I'm a novice when it comes to working with (or at least designing) databases so before diving in I figured I'd ask you folks if i'm on the right track! I'd like to design a database to hold some words as well as some peripheral information. Here is the information I would like to store:

Word, Definition, Definition Importance, Part of Speech, Synonym, Antonym

Would the following setup follow the 3nf standard?

Table One:
Primary Key - Word

Table Two: 
Primary Key - Part of Speech - Definition Importance - Definition

Table Three:
Primary Key - Synonym

Table Four:
Primary Key - Antonym

If it's compliant than that great! If not it'd be helpful to get a few suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not normalized. While you should be wary of trying to comply with an effectively abstract defintiion (1) there's a lot missing here.

Both your synonym and antinym tables should have a composite primary key decomposing the many to many relationship between an entry in the words table and the corresponding anti/syno-nym (also in the word table).

I have no idea what you mean by "Definition Importance". If this is for multiple definitions of the 'wor'd entity, rather the 'part of speech' entity, then it should be in the word table - similar for the other attributes you've listed in table 2.

BTW if you look at a purpose built dictionary system (such as aspell) the typically use a completely different, non-relational structure.

1) Normal form is far from abstract - but if you don't fully understand it, then it is effectively abstract. As long as you have a stronmg understanding of your data structure and how it will be manipulated then that should be your starting point. But this does not appear to be the case here.